# Primefaces MenuItem not firing ActionEvent

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, menu, model

I have a problem with a dynamically created menu model. I am using JSF 2.1.28 and Primefaces 3.4.5 (Primefaces 3.5.25 tested as well, same problem).

I have the following code:

XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/layout/layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="center">
        <p:panel style="width: 780px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: none;">
            <h:form>
                <h3>Menu test</h3>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="test" required="true" requiredMessage="This is required">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <p:commandButton id="menuButton" value="Show" type="button"/>
                <p:tieredMenu id="menu" model="#{menuBean.menu}" overlay="true" trigger="menuButton" my="left top" at="left bottom" />
            </h:form>
        </p:panel>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div id="center">
            <ui:insert name="center">
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "menuBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MenuBean {

    public MenuModel getMenu() {
        MenuModel menuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        menuItem.setId("testMenuItem");
        menuItem.setTitle("ActionTest");
        menuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        menuModel.addMenuItem(menuItem);
        return menuModel;
    }
}
```

Action listener

```
public class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

The action event that is supposed to be fired when the menu item is clicked is not fired. But if I selected an item in the SelectOneMenu and click the menu item again then the event will be fired. I have worked out that it has something to do with the "required" attribute on the SelectOneMenu because if I remove it all works fine.

Is this a bug in Primefaces and if so is there a workaround for it? If it is not a bug could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Setting the immediate attribute of all menu items to "true" solves the problem.

After solving this problem I ran into another one. I got a JSF exception and the message "Cannot remove the same component twice". A solution to this problem can be found here http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4431.